# Who is Khandoba Mahadev?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-purana

There is a temple in Maharashtra named 'Khandoba Temple'. In the temple, people worship Khandoba Mahadev. Who is he?

Comment: In Hindu context Mahadev always refers to Maha Shiva. Khandoba Mahadev also known as Martanda Bhairava is a form of Shiva himslef. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khandoba

Comment: SrikanthMyakam's answer is right!

Comment: Khandoba/Malhari is actually Martandabhairava - the Tantrika form of Surya. Due to the epithet Bhairava in his name, people mistake him to be a form of Shiva.

Comment: @অনু If Surya Martandabhairava, do he mentioned in scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

'Khandoba Mahadev' is a form of Shiva worshipped to around Maharashtra. He is a *kuladevata*, or a local deity, and a look [through](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gazetteer_of_the_Bombay_Presidency_Bij%C3%A1/2RIIAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22khandoba%20mahadev%22&pg=PA125&printsec=frontcover) [the](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gazetteer_of_the_Bombay_Presidency/-49IAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22khandoba%20mahadev%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover) [old](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gazetteer_of_the_Bombay_Presidency_Shol/ZrYBAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22khandoba%20mahadev%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover) [census](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gazetteer_of_the_Bombay_Presidency/N7oMAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22khandoba%20mahadev%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover) [records](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gazetteer_of_the_Bombay_Presidency/mrAAVSOj2hYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22khandoba%20mahadev%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover) show that nearly every Maharashtrian family listed him as one of the gods to whom they prayed. Since he's a local deity, he doesn't actually appear in any original texts, so there aren't any primary sources for this, though there is an extensive [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khandoba) article about him.